# How can I compare date results from duplicate item_number? I am looking for results that do not have a date before 09-30-2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains transaction history, it time stamps a column each time the item number is sold. It looks like this:

[image: Database Snapshot]

What I need to do is determine which Item's have not had **any** transaction history **since** `2016-09-30`.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM IVT_ITEMTRAN WHERE TRANS_DATE < '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

However the problem I run into with that is I am merely selecting every item with a timestamp before 2016-09-30.

How can I generate the results for items that have no history since the date I listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this would do what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM IVT_ITEMTRAN 
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER NOT IN
(
    SELECT ITEM_NUMBER
    FROM IVT_ITEMTRAN 
    WHERE TRANS_DATE < '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
)
```

Or if you just want the ItemNumbers you could use some aggregation.

```
select ITEM_NUMBER
    , EarliestDateSold = MIN(TRANS_DATE) 
from IVT_ITEMTRAN
group by ITEM_NUMBER
having MIN(TRANS_DATE) > '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Would you be able to talk me through what is happening there?

Comment: Sure. What part(s) don't you understand?

Comment: Well, When I run `SELECT * 
FROM dbo.admin_IVT_ITEMTRAN 
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER NOT IN
(
    SELECT ITEM_NUMBER
    FROM dbo.admin_IVT_ITEMTRAN 
    WHERE TRANS_DATE < '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
)`

It gives me dates that are newer than 2016-09-30

Comment: Isn't that what you said you wanted?

Comment: I need Item_numbers that have no history since 2016-09-30. When I run your query it gives me some that are newer.

Comment: Really? How? The subquery finds all ITEM_NUMBERS sold before 2016-09-30. Then the main query says give me ONLY items that are not in that list. Can you post ddl and sample to demonstrate this problem and the issue? Here is a great place to see what you should post. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This: 
`SELECT
b.WAREHOUSE_ID AS WAREHOUSE_ID,
a.ITEM_NUMBER, 
b.QTY_ON_HAND,
a.TRANS_DATE AS LAST_SEEN_ON_BOM,
b.LSTSAL_DATE AS LAST_SOLD_DIRECTLY
FROM 
dbo.admin_IVT_ITEMTRAN a, 
dbo.admin_IVM_ITEMWHSE b 
WHERE 
a.ITEM_NUMBER = b.ITEM_NUMBER 
AND 
b.LSTSAL_DATE < '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000' 
AND 
a.ITEM_NUMBER NOT IN
(
    SELECT ITEM_NUMBER
    FROM dbo.admin_IVT_ITEMTRAN 
    WHERE a.TRANS_DATE < '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
)
AND
b.WAREHOUSE_ID = 'CG'
AND 
a.WAREHOUSE_ID = 'CG'
ORDER BY LAST_SEEN_ON_BOM DESC`

Comment: There are so many issues in that code. First is antiquated join syntax (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), then aliases like a, b (https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). And your subquery is NOT the same thing because the where predicate in there is using the date from the outer query.

Comment: Can you help me clean it up? I'm lost

Comment: So did you get it figured out or do you still need help?